# How can I ignore all tags that include my ignored tags?

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags

I want to ignore all Pokemon games, so I added "pokemon" to my ignored tags, but it did nothing. To actually ignore Pokemon I would have to add all 20+ Pokemon-related tags to my ignored tags, and then continue adding any new Pokemon tags that arise.

How can I ignore all tags that include my ignored tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no setting to include partial matches of ignored tags, but you can use wildcards in your favorite or ignored tags.

As explained in an [answer on meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73100/ignore-tags-should-include-partial-or-related-tags-as-well), you can use the `*` character to denote zero to many matching characters. This works for both favorite tags and ignored tags. For example, ignoring `*pokemon*` will ignore all tags that have "pokemon" in them.

Comment: Do be careful with wildcards - you'd also be ignoring "SpokeMoney", etc. Obviously not a huge issue with Pokemon, but you might have issues if you try to ignore *cod* or similar.

Comment: For the same intended effect as `*pokemon*` but safer, one can often use multiple ignore entries with patterns like `pokemon*` and `*pokemon`, or to be even safer, `pokemon`, `pokemon-*`, and `*-pokemon`.

Comment: Good points guys. I actually used `pokemon*` myself, but I wanted to use something more general for the sake of example. Thankfully we use hyphens-to-denote-spaces rather than CamelCase for our tags, so ending up with a tag like "SpokeMoney" or "MetroIdea" is fairly unlikely.